# ImageView very slow

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I have the problem that my ScrollView is very slow and laggy.

I get these warning everytime I scroll:

```
Skipped 146 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

This is my XML file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/course1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c1text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/c1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="BlaBla1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView [...] />

    <TextView [...] />

    [more ImageViews and TextViews]
</RelativeLayout>
```

What solutions are there to optimize the loading of the images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious solution to this is to use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) as Android intended.

The reason for using a ListView is that it recycles its displays and thus maintains a minimal memory footprint. Coupled with the [ViewHolder pattern](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) and even with [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) libraries it can do preloading and caching easily and give you much better performance.

Unfortunately the only alternative is to manually preload images in the background, however this will eat through memory and likely get your application closed.

Comment: Is there a option to show the text under the image and not next to the image?

Comment: Yes,  A list view can use whatever layout you want as its itwm,  youre not forced to use the default simple ones if that's  what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, your images have the resolution more than you need for the screen. Rescale the images in advance, if possible.